# Is there a way to put a wildcard character in a web address when using rvest?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am new to web scrapping and using R and rvest to try and pull some info for a friend.  This project might be a bit much for my first, but hopefully someone can help or tell me if it is possible.

I am trying to pull info from https://www.veteranownedbusiness.com/mo like business name, address, phone number, and description.  I started by pulling all the names of the business' and was going to loop through each page to pull the information by business.  The problem I ran into is that the business url's have numbers assigned to them :
[www.veteranownedbusiness.com/business/**32216**/accel-polymers-llc](http://www.veteranownedbusiness.com/business/**32216**/accel-polymers-llc)

Is there a way to tell R to ignore this number or accept any entry in its spot so that I could loop through the business names?

Here is the code I have so far to get and clean the business titles if it helps:

```
library(rvest)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)

vet_name_list <- "https://www.veteranownedbusiness.com/mo"

HTML <- read_html(vet_name_list)

biz_names_html <- html_nodes(HTML, '.top_level_listing a')
biz_names <- html_text(biz_names_html)

biz_names <- biz_names[biz_names != ""]
biz_names_lower <- tolower(biz_names)
biz_names_sym <- gsub("[][!#$&%()*,.:;<=>@^_`|~.{}]", "", biz_names_lower)
biz_names_dub <- str_squish(biz_names_sym)  
biz_name_clean <-  chartr(" ", "-", biz_names_dub)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this substitution? You can simply extract the business names and urls (with numbers) and get further info from the urls that are actually valid? As the business names are also listed on the destination pages you can grab from there instead

Comment: @QHarr Mostly because i am new to web scrapping and didn't think about that as an option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I'm afraid you can't use wildcards to get a valid url. What you *can* do is to scrape all the correct urls from the page, number and all.

To do this, we find all the correct nodes (I'm using xpath here rather than css selectors since it gives a bit more flexibility). You then get the `href` attribute from each node.

This can produce a data frame of business names and url. Here's a fully reproducible example:

```r
library(rvest)
library(tibble)

vet_name_list <- "https://www.veteranownedbusiness.com/mo"

biz <- read_html(vet_name_list) %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//tr[@class='top_level_listing']/td/a[@href]")

tibble(business = html_text(biz),
       url = paste0(biz %>% html_attr("href")))
#> # A tibble: 550 x 2
#>    business                                               url                
#>    <chr>                                                  <chr>              
#>  1 Accel Polymers, LLC                                    /business/32216/ac~
#>  2 Beacon Car & Pet Wash                                  /business/35987/be~
#>  3 Compass Quest Joplin Regional Veteran Services         /business/21943/co~
#>  4 Financial Assistance for Military Experiencing Divorce /business/20797/fi~
#>  5 Focus Marines Foundation                               /business/29376/fo~
#>  6 Make It Virtual Assistant                              /business/32204/ma~
#>  7 Malachi Coaching & Training Ministries Int'l           /business/24060/ma~
#>  8 Mike Jackson - Author                                  /business/29536/mi~
#>  9 The Mission Continues                                  /business/14492/th~
#> 10 U.S. Small Business Conference & EXPO                  /business/8266/us-~
#> # ... with 540 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: `.top_level_listing [href*=business]` as a css selector alternative Name and url.

Comment: @QHarr thanks. I got into the habit of using explicit xpath as a sanity check, but that's certainly more concise.