# How to scrape links off a website in R? Unable to to scrape links

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the links off of [this website](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories*)

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
url=read_html('https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories*')

get_links <- url %>% 
  html_nodes('#resultsUrl a') %>% 
  html_attr('href') %>%
  paste0('https://web.archive.org/web/20220000000000*/', .)
get_links
```

But all I get is `character(0)`. I even tried looking for the `li class` as has been suggested to me before, but there is nothing useful.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that you're using wildcards in your url, e.g. [Is there a way to put a wildcard character in a web address when using rvest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73255316/12957340)?

Comment: Oh no! Is there any way to scrape wildcard url's with say, RSelenium or some other tool?

Comment: I'm also wondering if there is also another issue since I can't scrape anything from this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the links from their source

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)
library(janitor)

"https://web.archive.org/web/timemap/json?url=https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories&matchType=prefix&collapse=urlkey&output=json&fl=original,mimetype,timestamp,endtimestamp,groupcount,uniqcount&filter=!statuscode:[45]..&limit=10000&_=1663136483842" %>% 
  request() %>% 
  req_perform() %>% 
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  row_to_names(1)

# A tibble: 784 × 6
   original                                           mimet…¹ times…² endti…³ group…⁴ uniqc…⁵
   <chr>                                              <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
 1 https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/ca… text/h… 202209… 202209… 3       3      
 2 https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/ca… text/h… 202209… 202209… 6       6      
 3 https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/ca… text/h… 202209… 202209… 2       2      
 4 https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/ca… text/h… 202209… 202209… 1       1      
 5 https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/ca… text/h… 202209… 202209… 2       2      
 6 https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/ca… text/h… 202209… 202209… 1       1      
 7 https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/ca… text/h… 202209… 202209… 1       1      
 8 https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/ca… text/h… 202209… 202209… 2       2      
 9 https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/ca… text/h… 202209… 202209… 1       1      
10 https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/ca… text/h… 202209… 202209… 1       1      
# … with 774 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​mimetype, ²​timestamp, ³​endtimestamp,
#   ⁴​groupcount, ⁵​uniqcount
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: holy cow, that was incredible. I'm sure there's probably an insane explanation on how you did this, so can you instead tell me what resources you used to learn how to scrape the links? I'm not even sure where you got the link in the first line of code. It's not the same one I used. but this was amazing. I must know how you did it!

Comment: I thought I asked this already, but I don't see my follow-up question here, so I'll ask again. I just noticed this scraped the link text, but not the underlying link. If you click on each link, it does not take you to the actual website; it takes you to an archived version of that webpage. Those are the links I was trying to scrape. Is there a way to modify this to get the underlying links?

Comment: Disregard my second question! I just added a prefix to each of the links. Thank you!

Comment: In the network section in inspect element, you can see where the site is requesting data from. The R code  just emulates that request to get the same data!